# ¿A qué cuerno te tienes que ir cuando te mandan al cuerno?

Tags: expresiones, sustantivos

La palabra *[cuerno](https://dle.rae.es/cuerno)* cuenta con numerosas acepciones, desde el cuerno de los animales y las antenas de los atrópodos hasta instrumento viento e infidelidad matrimonial, pasando por las puntas de la luna cuando está en cuarto creciente o menguante. En este sitio ya hemos tenido algunas preguntas referentes a las acepciones y frases hechas con esta palabra:

- [¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "saber a cuerno quemado"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19412/12637)
- [Why in Spanish "putting horns" means to cheat your partner?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17904/12637)

Así que ahora nos vamos a centrar en otras de las expresiones que se pueden crear con esta palabra, a saber:

> **al cuerno**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. **a paseo.** *Lo tuve que mandar al cuerno. Váyase usted al cuerno.*
>
> **irse** algo **al cuerno**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Fracasar, frustrarse, estropearse. *Su negocio se ha ido al cuerno.*

Estas dos expresiones (y no sé si me atrevería a añadir *y un cuerno*, que expresa "negación o rechazo") deben de provenir de alguna de estas acepciones, indicando un sentido negativo de la palabra, o tal vez provengan de alguna otra expresión similar.

Así que el caso es saber, ¿a qué cuerno nos tenemos que ir cuando nos envían al cuerno?

> *Vete al cuerno, grandísimo reaccionario, que lo que es a mí no me encadenas tú...*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Miau", 1888 (España).

Answer (score 1):

*Expongo aquí mi teoría, mas aceptaré gustoso cualquier otra explicación razonable.*

**TL;DR:** Se refiere a los cuernos del toro.

Revisando el Autoridades de 1729, me encuentro con la siguiente entrada:

> Verse en los *cuernos* del toro. Phrase que explica hallarse en grave peligro de padecer algún gran daño, ù de perder la vida. Dicese por alusion de los que en las fiestas de toros se hallan en aprieto, de que se libran dificilmente.

Esta frase hecha, que todavía hoy perdura en el diccionario de la RAE, es bastante antigua, valga como ejemplo este fragmento:

> *¡A galanas!, no's caséys
>
>   por más que'l galán hos ame,
>
>   que'l buey suelto se lame.*
>
> *Mirad que hos digo verdad
>
>   que vays al cuerno del toro,
>
>   pues sabéys que libertad
>
>   no se paga con thesoro.*
>
> Juan de Timoneda, "Cancionero llamado Sarao de amor", 1561 (España).

En este texto podemos ver el uso de "ir al cuerno del toro" en el sentido de "os estáis metiendo en verdadero peligro" y usando *cuerno* en singular, en vez de *cuernos*. Entiendo que de aquí pudo surgir la expresión "irse al cuerno [del toro]" para indicar que algo ha fracasado (el toro lo ha embestido) o "váyase al cuerno" para desearle un mal a alguien (así te embista el toro con el cuerno).

Los primeros casos escritos los he visto, en todo caso, en la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de España, en ejemplares de mediados del siglo XIX.

> *Quien por sí su suerte labra,
>
>   se finje fiel al gobierno
>
>   y luego le manda al cuerno
>
>   olvidando su palabra,
>
>   por vueltas que dé la noria
>
>   al fin se llena de gloria.*
>
> La Posdata (Madrid). 25/11/1844, [página 3](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003547058&page=3&search=%22al%20cuerno%22&lang=es).

El problema que le veo a todo esto es que la expresión "estar en los cuernos del toro" data del siglo XVI, mientras que mandar a alguien o algo al cuerno no parece darse hasta el siglo XIX. Con tres siglos de por medio es posible que la expresión se refiera a otro tipo de cuerno. Mas esta me ha parecido una explicación plausible, así que la plasmo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que la alusión tenga que ver con *los cuernos del diablo*.

> Por lo que `mandar a alguien al cuerno` equivaldría a `mandarlo al diablo`

Se sabe que representación demoníaca tuvo influencias históricas de seres de la mitología griega, [tales como el fauno Pan](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_(mitolog%C3%ADa))

[image]

Tal relación puede leerse en [Cuernos, pezuñas e infierno: el diablo en la época medieval](https://www.nationalgeographic.co.uk/history-and-civilisation/2018/10/horns-hooves-and-hell-devil-medieval-times)

> Classical influences also played a role in the development of the
> Christian ­devil. As Christianity took root in the Roman world, early
> worshipers rejected pagan gods and believed them to be evil spirits.
> Pan, half goat and half man, was a lusty god of nature whose carnal
> appetites made him easy to associate with the forbidden. **His goat
> horns** and cloven hooves became synonymous with sin and would later be
> adopted by artists in their horrific images of the devil.
>
> Las influencias clásicas también jugaron un papel en el desarrollo del
> diablo cristiano. A medida que el cristianismo se arraigó en el mundo
> romano, los primeros adoradores rechazaron a los dioses paganos y
> creyeron que eran espíritus malignos. Pan, mitad cabra y mitad hombre,
> era un dios lujurioso de la naturaleza cuyos apetitos carnales lo
> hacían fácil de asociar con lo prohibido. **Sus cuernos de cabra** y sus
> pezuñas hendidas se convirtieron en sinónimo de pecado y luego serían
> adoptados por artistas en sus horribles imágenes del diablo.